# How to use Pixel Bender (pbj) in ActionScript3 on large Vectors to make fast calculations?

Tags: actionscript-3, fragment-shader, flashdevelop

Remember my old question: [2d game view camera zoom, rotation & offset using 'Filter' / 'Shader' processing?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38672/2d-game-view-camera-zoom-rotation-offset-using-filter-shader-processing)

I figured I could use a Pixel Bender Shader to do the computation for any large group of elements in a game to save on processing time. At least it's a theory worth checking.

I also read this question: [Pass large array to pixel shader](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35996/pass-large-array-to-pixel-shader)

Which I'm guessing is about accomplishing the same thing in a different language.

I read this tutorial: http://unitzeroone.com/blog/2009/03/18/flash-10-massive-amounts-of-3d-particles-with-alchemy-source-included/

I am attempting to do some tests. Here is some of the code:

```
        private const SIZE : int = Math.pow(10, 5);
        private var testVectorNum : Vector.<Number>; 

        private function testShader():void
        {
            shader.data.ab.value = [1.0, 8.0];
            shader.data.src.input = testVectorNum;

            shader.data.src.width = SIZE/400;
            shader.data.src.height = 100;
            shaderJob = new ShaderJob(shader, testVectorNum, SIZE / 4, 1);
            var time : int = getTimer(), i : int = 0;
            shaderJob.start(true);
            trace("TEST1 : ", getTimer() - time);
        }
```

The problem is that I keep getting a error saying:

`[Fault] exception, information=Error: Error #1000: The system is out of memory.`

Update:

I managed to partially workaround the problem by converting the vector into bitmapData:
(Using this technique I still get a speed boost of 3x using Pixel Bender)

```
    private function testShader():void
    {
        shader.data.ab.value = [1.0, 8.0];
        var time : int = getTimer(), i : int = 0;
        testBitmapData.setVector(testBitmapData.rect, testVectorInt);
        shader.data.src.input = testBitmapData;

        shaderJob = new ShaderJob(shader, testBitmapData);
        shaderJob.start(true);
        testVectorInt = testBitmapData.getVector(testBitmapData.rect);
        trace("TEST1 : ", getTimer() - time);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a complete solution to this issue.

Please notice size is now 10,000,000

Here is the new code snippet:

```
        private const SIZE : int = Math.pow(10, 7);
        private var testVectorInt : Vector.<Number>; //gotta use Number (not int)
        private var testVectorInt2 : Vector.<Number>; //Need separate vectors for I & O



        private function testShader():void
        {
            shader.data.ab.value = [1.0, 8.0];
            var time : int = getTimer(), i : int = 0;
            shader.data.src.input = testVectorInt;//testBitmapData;
            shader.data.src.width = SIZE/4000;
            shader.data.src.height = 1000;
            shaderJob = new ShaderJob(shader, testVectorNum, SIZE / 4000, 1000);//(shader, testVectorInt2, SIZE/4, 1);
            shaderJob.start(true);
            trace("TEST1 : ", getTimer() - time);
        }
    }
```

You might be wondering what is the speed difference?

Processing the Numbers one by one in a loop took: 1956ms

Doing it in Pixel Bender took: 189ms

This results is true for Flash Player 10.3 on my pc